# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in binary tree in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{            // here we are creating the structure of owr binary tree 
    struct node *leftNode;
    int val;
    struct node *rightNode; 
};                    // end of the struct
struct node *head = 0; 

void display(struct node *root);
void CreateTree(struct node *root,struct node *new);     // creating the function for creating the tree 

int main()          // start of the main method 
{
    int a;
    char wish;
    struct node *val;
    val=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    do{
    printf(" enter the number that you want to insert ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    val->val = a;
    val->rightNode = NULL;
    val-> leftNode = NULL;
    if(head == 0){
        head = val;
    }
    else {
        CreateTree(head,val);
    }
    printf(" do you want to continue in this [y/n]");
    scanf("%s",&wish);
    }while (wish != 'n');
    printf(" do you want to display your list [y/n]");
    scanf("%s",&wish);
    if (wish == 'y'){
      display(head);  
    }
    printf(" end of the programe \n ");
    return 0;
}
void CreateTree(struct node *root,struct node *new){
    if (new->val <= root->val){
        if(root->leftNode != NULL){
            CreateTree(root->leftNode,new);
        }
        else
        root->leftNode = new;
    }
    if (new->val > root->val){
        if(root->rightNode != NULL){
            CreateTree(root->rightNode,new);
        }
        else
        root->rightNode = new;
    }
}
void display(struct node *current){
   if(current->leftNode != NULL) 
    display(current->leftNode); 
    printf("%d",current->val);
    if(current->rightNode != NULL)
    display(current->rightNode);
```

}

I enter the number in my binary tree but when i type yes for display, it say  --> "segment fault(code dumped)"
this is the output --|

**enter the number that you want to insert 5
 do you want to continue in this [y/n]y
 enter the number that you want to insert 4
 do you want to continue in this [y/n]y
 enter the number that you want to insert 6
 do you want to continue in this [y/n]n
 do you want to display your list [y/n]y
Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

i have already seen the answers of other questions related to this, but i don't got the answer so please help me to short this problem

Comment: Have you noticed that you malloc just one single node?

Comment: `if(x <= y {} if(x > y) {}` are complementary - provided that no multi-threading side effects occur, second condition won't be true if first is and vice versa - so just have `if(x <= y) {}` **else** `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `val = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` in a do-while loop. Also, don't forget to free your memory

Comment: you don't have to cast that in C